# My tests are passing. But, undefined method `reviews' for nil:NilClass when calling the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Good afternoon people

I'm trying to build a tobacco review application, for no other reason than to learn some more stuff. I've been trying to build upon what I’ve learned in the Rails Tutorial book, however I keep coming up against brick walls and gotchas that I don't understand. I can normally get over the undefined method `something' for nil:NilClass and other issues i have, but this one's really get me stumped because I’ve got my tests passing.

**My Tests**

**review_test.rb**

```
require 'test_helper'

class ReviewTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

# Define a user for the test
def setup
@user = users(:shaun)
@review = @user.reviews.build( rating: 5, 
                               comment:"This is a super snus",
                               tobacco_id: 1)
end

# Test should be valid
test "should be valid" do
    assert @review.valid?
end

# Test the user id is present
test "user id should be present" do
    @review.user_id = nil
    assert_not @review.valid?
end

# Test the tobacco id is present
test "tobacco id should be present"  do 
    @review.tobacco_id = nil
    assert_not @review.valid?
end

# Rating should be present
test "rating should be present" do
    @review.rating = "   "
    assert_not @review.valid?
end

# Comment should be present
test "comment should be present" do 
    @review.comment = "    "
    assert_not @review.valid?
end

# Verify that the first review in the DB is the same as fixture review
test "order should be most recent first" do
    assert_equal reviews(:most_recent), Review.first
end

end
```

**user_test.rb**

```
# Test that a review is destroyed when a user is destroyed
test "associated reviews should be destroyed" do 
@user.save
@user.reviews.create!( rating: 5,
                       comment: "I love this suns, it's so good!",
                       tobacco_id: 1)
assert_difference 'Review.count', -1 do 
    @user.destroy
end
end
```

**Fixtures**

**reviews.yml**

```
one:
rating: 5
tobacco_id: 1
comment: "This is a super snus"
created_at: <%= 3.hours.ago %>

two:
rating: 5
tobacco_id: 1
comment: "This is the best snus in the world"
created_at: <%= 2.hours.ago %>

three:
rating: 5
tobacco_id: 1
comment: "I will always buy this snus"
created_at: <%= 1.hours.ago %>

 most_recent:
 rating: 5
 tobacco_id: 1
 comment: "I have a shed load of this snus, it's great!"
 created_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>
```

**Models**

**review.rb**

```
belongs_to :tobacco
```

**tobacco.rb**

```
has_many :reviews
```

**user.rb**

```
has_many :tobaccos, dependent: :destroy
has_many :reviews, dependent: :destroy
```

**Controller**
**reviews_controller.rb**

```
def new
@review = Review.new
end
```

This is what i have for the create action in the controller but i can't tell if i have this correct because i can't get the page to load yet. Any suggestions on the create action would be greatly appreciated to save asking another question if I have this wrong, which I probably have!

```
def create
    @tobacco = Tobacco.find(params[:tobacco_id])
    @review = @tobacco.reviews.new(params[:review].permit(:tobacco_id, :comment))
    @review.user = User.find(current_user.id)
    @review.save
    redirect_to tobacco_path(@tobacco)
end
```

**Routes**

```
resources :tobaccos do 
resources :reviews, except: [:show, :index]
end
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to "Write a Review", new_tobacco_review_path(@tobacco) %>
```

**new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for([@tobacco, @tobacco.reviews.build]) do |f| %>
<%= render 'fields', f: f %>
<%= f.submit "Save Review", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

When I get to the page to write a review, i get the error

```
Showing C:/Sites/apps/review/app/views/reviews/new.html.erb where line #11 raised:

undefined method `reviews' for nil:NilClass
```

It's telling me it's line 11

```
<%= form_for([@tobacco, @tobacco.reviews.build]) do |f| %>
```

but whatever I try I get a different error. I know it's a rookie mistake but i can't see it.

Thanks in advance

Shaun

UPDATE

I've got it working and saving to the database now, i did it like this
In the reviews_controller.rb the new and create look like this

```
def new
    @tobacco = Tobacco.find(params[:tobacco_id])
end


def create

@tobacco = Tobacco.find(params[:tobacco_id])
@review = Review.new(review_params)
@review.user_id = current_user.id
@review.tobacco_id = @tobacco.id

if @review.save
  redirect_to @tobacco
else
  render 'new'
end
end
```

The review_params are

```
def review_params
    params.require(:review).permit(:rating, :comment, :tobacco_id)
end
```

That all looks right to me, and it works so i hope it's all ok.

What i'm stuck on now is editing a review that belongs to a tobacco. This is the first time i've worked on nested routes. I just looked at a couple tutorials but nothing has really helped me to fix this. I am not sure how can I pass these keys...

On the show page i've got this

```
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_tobacco_review_path(@tobacco, @review) %>
```

The show method tobaccos_controller.rb looks like this

```
def show
    @tobacco = Tobacco.find(params[:id])
    @reviews = Review.where(tobacco_id: @tobacco.id)
end
```

In the reviews_controller.rb i've this

```
def edit
    @tobacco = Tobacco.find(params[:tobacco_id])
    @review  = Review.find(params[:id])
end
```

And the error i'm getting is this

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Tobaccos#show
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"reviews", :id=>nil, :tobacco_id=>"8"} missing required keys: [:id]
```

Looking at this i should be doing something in the Tobaccos#show action, but i can't think what.

I'm almost home and dry, can you see what i've done wrong? Thanks :)

**UPDATE NUMBER TWO show.html.erb**
It's not the whole show page, but it's the important part

```
<% if @reviews.blank? %>
    <h3>No reviews yet! Would you like to be the first?</h3>
    <%= link_to "Write Review", new_tobacco_review_path(@tobacco), class: "btn btn-danger" %>
<% else %>
    <% @reviews.each do |review| %>
 <div class="reviews">
    <p><%= review.comment %></p>
    <p><%= review.user.name %></p>
    <%= link_to "Edit", edit_tobacco_review_path(@tobacco, @review) %>
</div>
   <% end %>
<%= link_to "Write Another Review", new_tobacco_review_path(@tobacco), class: "btn btn-danger" %>
<% end %>
```

**UPDATE NUMBER 3 edit.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for([@tobacco, @tobacco.reviews.build]) do |f| %>
<%= render 'fields', f: f %>
<%= f.submit "Update Review", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
<%= link_to "Back", tobacco_path(@tobacco), 
class: "btn btn-default btn-block margin-top-25" %>
```

**_fields.html.erb**

```
<%= f.label  :rating %>
<%= f.select :rating, [['1', 1], 
                   ['2', 2], 
                   ['3', 3], 
                   ['4', 4], 
                   ['5', 5]
                  ] ,class: 'form-control' %>

<%= f.label :comment %>
<%= f.text_field :comment, class: 'form-control' %>
```

Comment: In your `new` action, you need to add `@tobacco = Tobacco.find(params[:tobacco_id])`

Comment: Thanks @Abm thats working but its not saving to the database, im guessing its line 2 of my create action. Can you shed any light on that for me please ?

Comment: Do you have strong_params method? Please post it.

Comment: @Pavan Sorry for the late reply i've been looking at the edit action now, please see my post mate

Comment: @pavan sorry mate, i posted an answer for you and i should have updated my post, i've done now

Comment: Try changing `@review = @tobacco.reviews.find(params[:id])` to `@review = Review.find(params[:id])`.

Comment: Sorry. try adding `@review = Review.find(params[:id])` to the `show` method

Comment: No, that didn't work

Comment: Can you post the show method in the question?

Comment: @pavan i've just sorted out the update for you, but i need to pop out for an hour

Comment: Did you tried adding `@review = Review.find(params[:id])` to the `show` method? also can you post full show page code,

Comment: @pavan I just posted the part of the show page you're interested in mate , i did try to add review  = Review.find(params[:id]) to the show but that didnt work

Comment: You need to change `<%= link_to "Edit", edit_tobacco_review_path(@tobacco, @review) %>` to `<%= link_to "Edit", edit_tobacco_review_path(@tobacco, review) %>`

Comment: @Pavan Almost! The edit page loads, but it doesn't have the review in the form

Comment: What do you mean by  it doesn't have the review in the form?

Comment: And also you shouldn't be asking everything in one question

Comment: @Pavan The original review isn't loaded into the edit view when the page loads up

Comment: Update your question with edit page code

Comment: @Pavan Done that mate

Comment: Post the _fields partial also please

Comment: @Pavan _fields partial updated

Answer (score 2):

> ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Tobaccos#show No route matches
>   {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"reviews", :id=>nil, :tobacco_id=>"8"}
>   missing required keys: [:id

You are iterating `@reviews` as `review`, so

this line

```
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_tobacco_review_path(@tobacco, @review) %>
```

should be

```
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_tobacco_review_path(@tobacco, review) %>
```